# How do I display the upcoming alternating Thursdays in PHP and have them not overwrite each other each week

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to write some php that outputs the delivery days for a store.

They deliver goods every Thursday, but to 2 locations and they alternate those locations weekly, so this Thursday they will deliver to Foo and the following Thursday they will deliver to Bar, then the following thursday they will deliver to Foo again and so on....

Ideally I'd like to output:

The next delivery to Foo is: [date]
The next delivery to Bar is: [date]

Apologies for my code, I've just started learning about time/datetime stuff and it confuses me!

I've have this which I based of another example:

```
<?php

    $nextThursday= strtotime("next Thursday");

    $secondThursday=strtotime("next Thursday",$nextThursday);

    echo "The next delivery to Foo is: <strong>" . date("l-jS-F",$nextThursday) . "</strong>, Please order before 7am on " . date("l-jS-F",$nextThursday) . " to ensure delivery.<br>";

    echo "The next delivery to Foo is: <strong>" . date("l-jS-F",$secondThursday) . "</strong>, Please order before 7am on " . date("l-jS-F",$secondThursday) . " to ensure delivery.<br>";
?>
```

But wasn't sure how to get this example working as once the current date gets to 'nextThursday' it will then say the delivery dates around the wrong way. Is there a simple way around this? Do I need to use a number of weeks somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just make sure the deliverydate is updated to next thursday in every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would like to generate a time schedule for delivery (say next 10 weeks?).

Assuming that you want to print the delivery schedule for the next 10 weeks' thursday and first delivery is go to 'Foo'. In that case we may

- use a loop
- make sure the delivery date is updated to next thursday at every iteration
- use Modulus operator (%) to "switch" from Foo to Bar and so on

```
<?php
// initalize to today first
$xdate = strtotime("Today");

for ($index=0; $index <10; $index++){
   $xdate = strtotime("Next Thursday", $xdate);
   echo "The next delivery to ". ($index%2==0 ? 'Foo':'Bar')    ." is: <strong>" . date("l-jS-F",$xdate) . "</strong>, Please order before 7am on " . date("l-jS-F",$xdate) . " to ensure delivery.<br><br>";
}
```

You may see the effect at the following sandbox link:

https://onlinephp.io/c/d1c98

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks that modulus operator is exactly what I needed I think! Thanks Ken, this pretty much answers my question, although your example prints 10 sentences and I only need to print what this thursday and what next thursday's deliveries are but I think I'll be able to make that work from your answer!

Comment: A fixed start date should be chosen for switching between “Foo” and “Bar”. If you always start at any time, the same recipient can be selected twice when moving to the next plan.

Comment: Just had a thought, rather than looping through 10 items would it make sense to check what week number next Thursday falls on and if the modulus of 2 == 0 it's Foo and if the modulus of 2 == 1 it's Bar?